# How to extract Host (domain) form apache_request_headers();

Tags: php, extract

How to extract the **domain** (host value) from the apache_request_headers(); output?

the original code:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

the result:

```
Host: yatko.net 
Connection: keep-alive 
Cache-Control: max-age=0 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

the desired output would be

```
yatko.net
```

I am having a strange issue with a mail form (http://goo.gl/Wr4sfC) and seems that apache_request_headers(); would work; however, I need to extract it from the generated array. Thank you!

Comment: Using the phrase "extract" instead of simply "accessing the array element" indicates that you skipped a [basic section in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question.

```
echo $headers['Host'];
// yatko.net
```

Comment: I suppose so, but avoid regex whenever you can. If it's for URLs, use `parse_url` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Isn't that what this question is all about??? You've got it from `$headers['Host']`!

Comment: This is my last input on for you on this, `$headers['Host']` contains `yatko.net`, that **doesn't have a WWW in front of it**. Just use that variable and don't bother trying to strip WWW off when it's not there.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Thank you!